# Sniffing serial port /dev/ttyS0 while another application is using it

Tags: linux, serial-port, tty, packet-sniffers

My platform: Linux Kubuntu 14

I am currently working on a project in which my application is communicating with a process via rs232 connected to /dev/ttyS0 serial port.

Sometimes incoming messages aren't intercepted by my process so I decided to use a sniffing tool called jpnevulator.

From what I see, if I run my application together with the sniffing tool, some messages are intercepted by the sniffing tool and some by my application, but not both.

Is it not possible to listen via sniffing tool on a serial port while another application is using it?

Thanks

Comment: Reading that thing's documentation, it sounds like you either want to have 2 other serial ports, and have jpnevulator do passthrough between the two (from original source, out through second to the port you're using), or possibly have it set up a PTY, and do passthrough between that and the serial port. How were you using the tool? See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12359

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478528/how-do-i-use-jpnevulator-to-capture-and-log-the-serial-traffic-between-an-applic and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469573/sniffing-serial-port-jpnevulator-sniffs-only-some-bytes

Comment: Currently I use jpnevulator as follows: jpnevulator --read --ascii --tty=/dev/ttyS0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socat serial port sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868351/socat-serial-port-sniffing)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the helpful responses.
As suggested in [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478528/how-do-i-use-jpnevulator-to-capture-and-log-the-serial-traffic-between-an-applic)

I used interceptty to link a pseudo terminal to the serial port I am listening to and connected my application to the pseudo terminal and it worked.